# Construct an equivalent representation where r is diagonal.

Tags: group-theory

Consider the group $D_3$ deﬁned via $\ r^3 = f^2 = e$ and with $r\cdot f \cdot r \cdot f=e$ (not $r\cdot f = f \cdot r$). We have formed a 2-dimensional representation of it which is naturally found by considering the group as acting on an equilateral triangle. In the representation we have found that $f$ is diagonal. Now construct an equivalent representation where $r$ is diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Diagonalize the matrix of $r$ over $\mathbb C$. Since $r$ is a rotation matrix and the angle of rotation is $2\pi/3$ we have that $r$ must have eigenvalues $e^{\pm 2\pi i /3}$.